# Bauded Lorenz Parameter in odeint

Tags: python, parameter-passing, odeint

I am trying to create a Lorenz solution whereby one of the parameters is modulated.

In creating a straightforward set of Lorenz equations, using odeint is simple:

```
Multiplier = 10. # Use multiplier to widen bandwidth 

Sigma = Multiplier * 16.
Rho =   Multiplier * 45.6
Beta =  Multiplier * 4

##################################
#
#   dx/dt = Sigma(y-x)
#   dy/dt = Rho*x - y-20xz
#   dz/dt = 5xy - Beta*z
#
##################################

def f(y, t, param):
    Xi = y[0]
    Yi = y[1]
    Zi = y[2]
    Sigma = param[0]
    Rho = param[1]
    beta = param[2]    
    f0 = Sigma*(Yi -Xi)
    f1 = Rho*Xi - Yi - 20*Xi*Zi
    f2 = 5*Xi*Yi - beta*Zi
    return [f0, f1, f2]

# Initial Conditions    
X0 = 1.0
Y0 = 1.0
Z0 = 1.0
y0 = [X0, Y0, Z0]
t = np.arange(0, 10, .001)  #Create 10 seconds of data
dt = t[1] - t[0]
param = [Sigma, Rho, Beta]

# Solve the DEs
soln = odeint(f, y0, t, args = (param,))
X = soln[:, 0]
Y = soln[:, 1]
Z = soln[:, 2]
```

The above code works perfectly to create a simple Lorenz system.  I would now like to create a modulated parameter Lorenz system to study its effectiveness in communications.  This can be done by modulating the parameter Beta.  Beta(t) can take on one of two values, 4.0 or 4.4 to represent '0' or '1'.

In order to modulate beta, I chose random 1's and 0's and assigned them to two values of beta, 4.0 and 4.4, at 500 samples per '1' or '0'.

```
Bit_Rate = 2.
Number_of_Bits = np.int(len(X)*dt*Bit_Rate)
Number_of_samples_per_bit = np.int(1/ dt / Bit_Rate)


Bauded_Beta = []
for i in range(0, Number_of_Bits):
    Bit = np.random.randint(0,2)
    if Bit == 0:
        for j in range(Number_of_samples_per_bit):
            Bauded_Beta.append(Multiplier * 4.4)
    else:
        for k in range(Number_of_samples_per_bit):
            Bauded_Beta.append(Multiplier * 4.0)
```

I then changed the call to the odeint set of parameters to:
param = [Sigma, Rho, Bauded_Beta]

```
param = [Sigma, Rho, Bauded_Beta]

# Solve the DEs
soln = odeint(f, y0, t, args = (param,))
X = soln[:, 0]
Y = soln[:, 1]
Z = soln[:, 2]
```

When I run this, I get the following error message, "Illegal input detected (internal error).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."

I know this error is from beta no longer being constant.  But, how do I pass a modulated parameter to odeint?